# Using ajax to update a container

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have an asp.net webform which has a div element named 'contents' and a textbox on it. The div is loaded with some html, which I've retrieved into a string in the codebehind file. Inside this html, I need to be able to mark up various bits of text so that when a user clicks them, it sends a message back to the server, which then populates the text box (which is on the same form) with some other data.

The problem I'm having is how best to communicat back to the server- so in the code below,

1) What should the line alert("You clicked " + x); be, so that it uses ajax to call back to the server, sending the parameter 'hello'

2) What method would be invoked on the server? Would it be Page_Load again?

3) After having called the server, what code would I need to popluate the text box without sending back the whole page again (i.e. still using ajax)?  The problem is not retrieving the text on the server, let's just say I receive 'hello' as a parameter on the server, and want to send back 'goodbye' to the text box, again using ajax

So my source aspx file has this in it...

and in my codebehind file in form_load, I have..

```
System.IO.StreamReader rdr = System.IO.File.OpenText("c:\\myHtmlFile.html");
string s = rdr.ReadToEnd();
this.contents.InnerHtml = s;
```

the HTML I'm loading into the div element is this

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function myfunction(x)
     { 
  alert("You clicked " + x);
         }
 </script>

 <p  onclick="myfunction('hello')">hello</p>
```

When the user clicks 'hello', I want TextBox1 to say 'goodbye'. Again, it's the server that has to handle things here, without reposting the webpage though..

Anyone have any ideas? The simpler the better please! thanks in advance...

Comment: what is content of myHtmlFile.html?

Comment: Behnam - it's just text and a few images- it could even be as simple as the HTML I've typed above, i.e. a javascript function and a single line of HTML that the user clicks on. The problem is what happens after the click: what's the simplest way to send a parameter to the server, and what's the simplest and fastest way of sending back the return value 'goodbye' to the browser,so that it updates the textbox, which remember is *not* in the <div> that hosted the original HTML...

Comment: which version of asp.net u use?

Comment: visual studio 2010, framework version 4...

Comment: why u don't use update panel?

Comment: Behnam, thanks for that, but the file in the div element is plain HTML (I have no choice about that) and I don't think I can embed an asp.net control into it. The rest of the form is written in asp.net. Do you know a way of doing it as the qustion stands??

Comment: you have two choices 1 : web Service 2: using ICallBackHandler Interface.

Comment: if you want to pass an arg and get a string result the second approach is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

check Microsoft's Documentation for Implementing this interface:

[ICallbackEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx)

hope this help.